# Gulp - unexpected token error using gulp-uglify and gulp-concat

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, uglifyjs

Here is my code

```
gulp.task('js', function () {
return gulp.src(['public/js/angular.js','public/js/app.js', 'public/js/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(plumber({
        errorHandler: function(err){
            console.log(err);
            this.emit('end');
        }
    }))
    .pipe(concat('filename.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify().on('error', gutil.log))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js') //destination of new file
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Finished minifying JavaScript'})))

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('app/assets/sass/**/*', ['css']);
    gulp.watch('public/js/**/*', ['js']);
});
```

Console error after change made to any js file:

> /projects/miche-web/public/js/miche.min.js: Unexpected token name «replace», expected punc «,»]
>   message: '/Users/projects/miche-web/public/js/miche.min.js: Unexpected token name «replace», expected punc «,»',
>   fileName: '/Users/projects/miche-web/public/js/miche.min.js',
>   lineNumber: 247,

However, the file is blank so I can't reference an error on line 247.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The error occurs on the generated file or in the gulp task?

Comment: It occurs in the gulp task but references the file that is created with the concat(). Error references a line number for that file, but the file is blank. I'm baffled.

Comment: You have no example above that  shows a gulp "watch" so please post more code or we can't help you.

Comment: Thanks. More code added. Hope it's helpful.

Comment: I'm getting the impression that my js files have errors in them and it's referencing the line number of where that code will go after it's minified. Kind of difficult to debug.

Comment: Did you rename miche.min.js to  filename.min.js  ?

Comment: No, I accidentally did that here. It's all the same in my code.

Comment: It's hard for us to follow if the error message doesn't match the code sample you provide.

Comment: @nix Exactly my issue. The error wasn't referencing any valid code. I figured it out though. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your `pipe` call. Observe the following...

```
.pipe(gulp.dest('public/js') //destination of new file
```

=>

```
.pipe(gulp.dest('public/js')) //destination of new file
```

notice the missing `)` on your initial function call

Comment: Thanks for catching that! Oddly enough it was still working. I discovered the error because I found some PHP code that was not removed from the JavaScript. It could not minify because of that but now it works fine after I removed it.

Comment: hehe strange that it works. Either way you solved it and that's what is important!

Comment: Exactly!  Very odd one here. Now I know for next time that I see this.